# ASP.NET 5 MVC6 Error: project is not a web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I cloned an existing ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 project from a private git repository. When I run the project I receive the following error:

`The selected debug option is IIS Express but this project is not a web project. To use IIS Express you need tho add the wwwroot attribute to project.json.`
[image: error]

The wwwroot folder is also not shown correctly and is displayed as a normal folder.

[image]

Installed Visual Studio 2015 - Update 1

Comment: did you also install aspnet 5 rc1 update 1 from http://get.asp.net ?

Comment: @herrh VS 2015 update 1 only has beta8. It would be highly recommended to go to get.asp.net and download the newest version.

Comment: @janpieter_z okay, I will update it. I Think this will solves my problem.

Comment: You can add this comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

make sure you install asp.net rc1 update 1 from http://get.asp.net

Comment: Did you mean RC1 Update 1? There is no update 12 as of yet. And I have it and still face this issue.

Comment: yeah sorry, typo, I didn't notice, fixed

Comment: My issue was slightly different. I didn't have a `wwwroot` (had it renamed to `public`) and IISExpress was choking on that. Kestrel seems fine with the rename.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.

For me, adding this line to the top of the project.json file solved the issue.

```
"webroot": "wwwroot",
 "version": "1.0.0-*",
```

Comment: This helped me solve a similar issue, just updating project.json with the webroot worked

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to install DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3 for VS 2015

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827546

An old project I am maintaining uses Core 1.0.1. - HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the accepted answer (since I ran into the same problem), you want to download ASP.NET 5 RC (aka ASP.NET Core 1.0) from http://get.asp.net, *not* ASP.NET 4.6.

Hopefully that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a new project(File => New project):

1. Select templates
2. Visual C#
3. Web
4. ASP.NET Web Application => Ok
5. On the **Select a template view**, dobbelt click: **Get ASP.NET 5 RC**

You wil now dowload the install file: **AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909**